# Is there any possibility of spark.scheduler.pool (local property ) set from spark-submit

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hadoop-yarn, spark-submit

I am using a fair scheduler along with yarn

`spark.scheduler.pool` is a local property to set to spark context while executing jobs, for a configured pool.

like..

```
val sc: SparkContext = ???
sc.setLocalProperty("spark.scheduler.pool", "myPool")
```

I was just wondering is there any possibility to set this local property from `spark-submit` command like `-Dspark.scheduler.pool=xxx`

Comment: @himanshuIIITian : Any idea of whether this is possible ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, `spark.scheduler.pool` can be set to any value from `spark-submit` using the following syntax -

```
spark-submit --master local --conf spark.scheduler.pool=myPool --class classpath jarfile
```

I hope it helps!

Comment: this is not working as expected. pools are configured and I gave the property `--conf` from `spark-submit` not `setLocalProperty` but its taking default pool. i am using client and cluster mode some times not local

Comment: @user3190018 Can you please share the output of `sc.conf.getAll`?